# Lost in conditionalpanels; complex conditions

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny user interface for a rather complex function.

First, I want the user to select between a and b, and then, conditional on the selection, I want to display input selectors X and Y with largely similar items (thing 1, 2, etc.). Lastly, conditional on these choices, I want to display different sliders and selectors for thing 1, 2, etc.

Aside: In the function (left out here) X and Y (think of, e.g., plot axis) define where the values of thing 1, 2, 3 get passed as arguments.

My attempt, however, does not work (e.g. the notification only works when "a" is selected), and I'm kind of lost in the conditional panel logic.

Example app.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
ui <- navbarPage(
    title = "test",
    windowTitle = "Test",
    tabPanel("Tab 1",
            sidebarPanel(
                selectInput(
                    "tbd", 
                    "I want...",
                    c(
                        "a" = "a",
                        "b" = "b"
                    )
                ),  
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.tbd == 'a'",
                    selectInput(
                        "y",
                        "Y",
                        c(
                            "Thing 1" = "thing1",
                            "Thing 2" = "thing2",
                            "Thing 3" = "thing3"
                        )
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                        "x",
                        "X",
                        c(
                            "Thing 1" = "thing1",
                            "Thing 2" = "thing2",
                            "Thing 3" = "thing3"
                        )
                    )
                ),
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.tbd == 'b'",
                    selectInput(
                        "y",
                        "Y",
                        c(
                            "Thing 2" = "thing2",
                            "Thing 3" = "thing3"
                        )
                    ),
                    selectInput(
                        "x",
                        "X",
                        c(
                            "Thing 1" = "thing1",
                            "Thing 2" = "thing2",
                            "Thing 4" = "thing4"
                        )
                    )
                ),
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.y == input.x"
                ),                    
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.tbd != 'a' && 
                                 input.y != input.x",
                    sliderInput(
                        "input2",
                        "Input thing 2",
                        min = 0,
                        max = 1,
                        value = c(0.2, 0.6)
                    )
                ),
                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.tbd != 'a' &&
                                    input.x != thing2 &&
                                    input.byaxis != thing2",
                    numericInput(
                        "input2",
                        "Input thing 2",
                        min = 0,
                        max = 1,
                        value = 0.5
                    )
                )
            ),      
    ),
    tabPanel("Tab 2"),
    tabPanel("Tab 3")
)



server <- function(input, output) {

    observe({
        if (input$y == input$x) {
            return(showNotification("You can't select the same thing for X and Y"))
        }
    })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you define input `x` more than one time, because you have several conditional panels which all refer to the same input. This won't work in shiny. You can give them the same `label` but they need to have a different `id`.

Then you sometimes referred to `thing2` inside the condition of the conditional panel, but you need to quote it as  `'thing2'`.

Following this advice you should be able to specify your conditions correctly. However, if the logic gets very complex, as in your case, it might be advisable to use `renderUI` on the server side.

Here is a start building up on your example.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "test",
  windowTitle = "Test",
  tabPanel("Tab 1",
           sidebarPanel(
             selectInput(
               "tbd", 
               "I want...",
               c(
                 "a" = "a",
                 "b" = "b"
               )
             ),  
             conditionalPanel(
               condition = "input.tbd == 'a'",
               selectInput(
                 "ya",
                 "Y",
                 c(
                   "A Thing 1" = "thing1",
                   "A Thing 2" = "thing2",
                   "A Thing 3" = "thing3"
                 )
               ),
               selectInput(
                 "xa",
                 "X",
                 c(
                   "A Thing 1" = "thing1",
                   "A Thing 2" = "thing2",
                   "A Thing 3" = "thing3"
                 )
               )
             ),
             conditionalPanel(
               condition = "input.tbd == 'b'",
               selectInput(
                 "yb",
                 "Y",
                 c(
                   "B Thing 2" = "thing2",
                   "B Thing 3" = "thing3"
                 )
               ),
               selectInput(
                 "xb",
                 "X",
                 c(
                   "B Thing 1" = "thing1",
                   "B Thing 2" = "thing2",
                   "B Thing 4" = "thing4"
                 )
               )
             ),
             # conditionalPanel(
             #   condition = "input.y == input.x"
             # ),                    
             conditionalPanel(
               condition = "input.tbd != 'a' && 
                                 input.yb != input.xb",
               sliderInput(
                 "input2",
                 "Input if not a and y!=x",
                 min = 0,
                 max = 1,
                 value = c(0.2, 0.6)
               )
             ),
             conditionalPanel(
               condition = "input.tbd != 'a' &&
                                    input.xb == input.yb",
               numericInput(
                 "input2",
                 "Input if not a and y = x",
                 min = 0,
                 max = 1,
                 value = 0.5
               )
             )
           ),      
  ),
  tabPanel("Tab 2"),
  tabPanel("Tab 3")
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the same logic using `renderUI`. `conditionalPanel` is faster, because it is rendered on the UI side alone without using the server side. However. using `renderUI` makes it easier to create inputs with the same id based on a complex control flow.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "test",
  windowTitle = "Test",
  tabPanel("Tab 1",
           sidebarPanel(
             selectInput(
               "tbd", 
               "I want...",
               c(
                 "a" = "a",
                 "b" = "b"
               )
             ),  
             uiOutput("y"),
             uiOutput("x"),
             uiOutout("input2")
             
             )),
  tabPanel("Tab 2"),
  tabPanel("Tab 3")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$y <- renderUI({
    
    if (input$tbd == "a") {
      vals <- c(
        "A Thing 1" = "thing1",
        "A Thing 2" = "thing2",
        "A Thing 3" = "thing3"
      )
    } else {
      vals <- c(
        "B Thing 2" = "thing2",
        "B Thing 3" = "thing3"
      )
    }

    selectInput(
      "y",
      "Y",
      vals
    )
  })
  
  output$x <- renderUI({
    
    req(input$tbd)
    if (input$tbd == "a") {
      
      vals <- c(
        "A Thing 1" = "thing1",
        "A Thing 2" = "thing2",
        "A Thing 3" = "thing3"
      )
    } else {
      vals <- c(
        "B Thing 1" = "thing1",
        "B Thing 2" = "thing2",
        "B Thing 4" = "thing4"
      )
    }
    
    selectInput(
      "x",
      "X",
      vals
    )
  })
  
  output$input2 <- renderUI({
    
    req(input$x)
    req(input$y)
    
    if (input$tbd != "a" && input$x == input$y) {
      
      numericInput(
        "input2",
        "Input if not a and y = x",
        min = 0,
        max = 1,
        value = 0.5
      )

    } else if (input$tbd != "a" && input$x != input$y) {

      sliderInput(
        "input2",
        "Input if not a and y!=x",
        min = 0,
        max = 1,
        value = c(0.2, 0.6)
      )
    }
    
 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of using renderUI? Speed? How does it simplify the above? What's annoying about not beeing able to use the same id is that I now have to pass all inputs one by one, instead of having one function call/functional in the server function.